# updating a record based on id and checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, get

Essentially, i'm trying to show the information about what the user has it lists their

```
BookID date time confirmed
```

confirmed is a 0 or 1, 0 is not confirmed 1 is confirmed, as this is a table this needs to be done with $_GET i'm assuming or it wont update the correct one.

at the moment I have this for the table listing the things

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  { ?>
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $row['BookID']?></td>
  <td>  <?php echo $row['date']?>  </td>
  <td>  <?php echo $row['time']?>  </td>
  <td> <input type="checkbox" name="Confirmed" value="1" <?php echo ($row['Confirmed'] == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>/> </td>
  <td><a href="delete.php?BookID=<?php echo $row['BookID']; ?>">Delete</a></td>
  <td><a href="update.php?BookID=<?php echo $row['BookID']; ?>">Update</a></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

update.php contains this

```
<?php
// Your database info
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = 'smithrwg_database';

$Confirmed = $_POST['Confirmed'];

if (!isset($_POST['Confirmed']))
{
    echo 'No ID was given...';
    exit;
}

$con = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if ($con->connect_error)
{
    die('Connect Error (' . $con->connect_errno . ') ' . $con->connect_error);
}
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_booking SET Confirmed = '$Confirmed' WHERE BookID = ?");

//$sql = "UPDATE tbl_booking SET Confirmed='$Confirmed' WHERE BookID == ?";
if (!$result = $con->prepare($sql))
{
    die('Query failed: (' . $con->errno . ') ' . $con->error);
}

if (!$result->bind_param('i', $_GET['BookID']))
{
    die('Binding parameters failed: (' . $result->errno . ') ' . $result->error);
}

if (!$result->execute())
{
    die('Execute failed: (' . $result->errno . ') ' . $result->error);
}

if ($result->affected_rows > 0)
{
    echo "The ID was updated with success.";
}
else
{
    echo "Couldn't update the ID.";
}
$result->close();
$con->close();
```

with my main focus being on the $sql, as it isnt actually getting the id from the get function.

the checkbox is getting the value from the database to see if it should be checked already or not, i want to be able to click it again and "un-confirm" or confirm it if it didn't have a tick.

Comment: why $_POST['Confirmed'] and not $_GET['Confirmed']?

Comment: changed that to $_GET it didn't really do anything. also changed `<td><a href="update.php?BookID=<?php echo $row['BookID']; ?>">Update</a></td>` to `<td><a href="update.php?BookID=<?php echo $row['BookID']; ?>?Confirmed=<?php echo $row['Confirmed']; ?>">Update</a></td>`

Comment: And this line too? if (!isset($_POST['Confirmed']))

Comment: change the second ? to &: <a href="update.php?BookID=<?php echo $row['BookID']; ?>&Confirmed=<?php echo $row['Confirmed']; ?>">Update</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you use for method attribute in your form tag? If you use GET, then use a GET to fetch it. If you use POST, then use a POST. By the way, try to echo all of the posted variables first so that you know that you are passing correct variable. It is always a good debugging method. Hope this helps. Thank you.